# Decrease audio volume below 1% without muting

Tags: audio, usb-audio

The output volume of my USB headphones ("Microsoft Lifechat LX-3000", ID: "LX3000") is too loud. This happens on Windows too, so I suspect its a problem with the headphones themselves. Is there a way to reduce the volume, below 1% without muting, for this device only?

Comment: You use the tag `usb-audio`. Does that mean you are using a USB audio interface? Which one? Normally, you can change the volume for those devices using `alsamixer` and automate that through `amixer`.

Comment: They are USB headphones and I'm using the default setup for them - just the config options from right clicking the volume control.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried running alsamixer (from a terminal; then press F6 to select the USB headphones).

Comment: Yeah, same problem occurs there.

Comment: Check this link out: [01](https://chrisjean.com/fix-for-usb-audio-is-too-loud-and-mutes-at-low-volume-in-ubuntu/)